# Download a file and post-process it on Heroku - Flask

Tags: flask, heroku

I am planning to download a youtube video with the youtube-dl python library, convert it to mp3, do some extra stuff with ffmpeg and display it to the user in an html page.

All of this through Flask.

I've been reading Heroku has a Ephemeral filesystem, so is my idea above possible at all?

- This is for a school project, so I don't have any budget for it.
- I am not interested in keeping the generated file. Just the client is.

Comment: If you upload the end result to a non-ephemeral location like Amazon S3, sure. https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/s3

Comment: @ceejayoz, is it possible to instead store the final result on the client's computer? To avoid using S3 at all? I am not interested in the generated file.

Comment: Yes, if you can do it in under 30 seconds. https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/request-timeout

Comment: @ceejayoz Ahh interesting! Thanks for your help! If I understand correctly, my download could take less than 30 seconds, can take whatever amount of time for the local post-processing (ffmpeg) and then make the final file upload it and make it less than 30 seconds as well and should work?

Comment: No, the ffmpeg processing, if you're going to be doing that on Heroku, either needs to a) run as a worker dyno and put its results somewhere like S3 or b) be able to complete all its processing in under 30 seconds if you want it to run as a web dyno.

Comment: Ahh I understand now, Thank you for your help! I think I'll try first with the web dyno and see if that works.